# How to make select dropdown menu height smaller in React Js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

I'm using select dropdown menu in my React Js app and I can't find a way to make the dropdown menu's height smaller with scrollbar. My code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and css

```
option {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font: 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-frog-l0m09?file=/src/styles.css:102-263)

When I choose option in css I can style background and color, but when I try to add height 50px for ex,  it doesn't work. What I would love to achieve is to have a dropdown menu with a little height(so dropdown menu itself wouldn't go all the way down if there are too many options) and a scrollbar. Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: @Rolando Yera, this example has a long dropdown menu, if I have 20 optionsm dropdown will be way to long,

Answer (score 0):

Use the size attribute to set the number of lines.

For example,

```
<select size=4>
```

Comment: S, hi, it just displays 4 options on page load, not 1line input

Comment: If you want a one line input you can use size 1 but styling wise you may want to go for an arrow drop down menu instead of a scrolling choice list